# Bindable property return only default value

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want create user control (user view) in xamarin.forms. My contol has one property. Control choose what the element would be add to the page (Entry or Label). For it I use BindableProperty, but it return only default value. I dont understand what wrong?

Here my user control code:

```
 public partial class UserView : ContentView
{
    public UserView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        if (TypeElement == "label")                              //TypeElement return only "default value"
            stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "LABEL" });
        else
            stackLayout.Children.Add(new Entry { Text = "ENTRY" });

        Content = stackLayout;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TypeProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("TypeElement", typeof(string), typeof(UserView), "default value");

    public string TypeElement
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use my control on page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TypeElement property is getting set after the constructor completes, you should be watching for when this property changes and then do what you need to do, for example:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TypeProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("TypeElement", typeof(string), typeof(UserView), "default value", propertyChanged:OnTypeElementChanged);

private static void OnTypeElementChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var userView = bindable as UserView;
    StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
    if (userView.TypeElement == "label")                              //TypeElement return only "default value"
        stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "LABEL" });
    else
        stackLayout.Children.Add(new Entry { Text = "ENTRY" });

    userView.Content = stackLayout;
}
```

I have tested this and it works, there are a couple of things about your implementation that confuse me though, such as why you are using an attached property instead of a regular bindable property, and also why you seem to have a XAML file associated with UserView if you're just going to replace the content anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You very helped me.

Comment: About my question. I try to create user control, which have some property, for example "CountTextBox", "CountLabel" and e.t.c. This property I want fill in XAML and then get complex control. My target - some "dynamic" control.